# How to repeatedly add text on both sides of a word in vim?

Tags: vim, editor, vi

I have a bunch of local variable references in a Python script that I want to pull from a dictionary instead. So, I need to essentially change `foo`, `bar`, and others into `env['foo']`, `env['bar']` and so on. Do I need to write a regular expression and match each variable name to transform, or is there a more direct approach that I could just repeat with the `.` command?

Comment: Great question; I use the "surround.vim" (search on google) for spaces, but surrounding by parenthesis/brackets and prepending a function name or dictionary name would be fantastic. I respectfully suggest you wait to see if a better answer than the current 3 surfaces...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a macro: type these commands in one go (with spacing just to insert comments)

```
             " first move to start of the relevant word (ie via search)
qa           " record macro into the a register.
ienv['<esc>  " insert relevant piece
ea']         " move to end of word and insert relevant piece
q            " stop recording
```

then, when you're on the next word, just hit `@a` to replay the macro (or even `@@` to repeat the last replay after that).

Comment: That's a character or two shorter than what I had. Thanks! I've been neglecting recorded macros, and I should start using them more often.

Comment: Depending on how your words are organized, you can place the cursor at the start of the next word before stopping recording. Then just repeat the recorded macro n-1 times (as the first word you have already changed to record the macro)

Comment: I have `:vmap @ :normal! @` mapped in my vimrc so that I can execute a macro on a visually selected range of lines as well as `n` times. This works by visually selecting, hitting `@`, typing the letter of the macro and then finally hitting enter.

Answer (score 5):

There's an easier way - you can use a regex search and replace. Go into cmdline mode by typing a colon and then run this command:

```
%s/\\(foo\|bar\|baz\\)/env['\1']/
```

Replacing `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` with whatever your actual variable names are. You can add as many additional variables as you'd like, just be sure to escape your OR pipes with a backslash. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

you could write a function that would do this pretty well, add this to your .vimrc file:

```
function! s:surround()
    let word = expand("<cword>")
    let command = "%s/".word."/env[\'".word."\']/g"
    execute command
endfunction
map cx :call <SID>surround()<CR>
```

This will surround every occurance of the word currently under the cursor.

If you wanted to specify what went before and after each instance you could use this:

```
function! s:surround()
    let word = expand("<cword>")
    let before = input("what should go before? ")
    let after = input("what should go after? ")
    let command = "%s/".word."/".before.word.after."/g"
    execute command
endfunction
map cx :call <SID>surround()<CR>
```

If you only want to confirm each instance of the variable you could use this:

```
function! s:surround()
    let word = expand("<cword>")
    let before = input("what should go before? ")
    let after = input("what should go after? ")
    let command = "%s/".word."/".before.word.after."/c"
    execute command
endfunction
map cx :call <SID>surround()<CR>
```

Comment: Can that be parameterized with a prefix and postfix for more general use?

Comment: Also, that operates on the entire line. How about just the word under the cursor?

Comment: I'm sure it could be parameterized but to be honest I am not very familiar with vim functions and so I don't know how it would be done. you could get user input with `let before = input("What text should go before ".word."? ")`
this would take more time per replace but would be more flexible. I'll edit the answer with a version that includes this.

Comment: In my testing this replaces every instance of the current word in the file. Are you wanting it to only act on one word at a time? I'll update the answer with an option that would do that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one way to do what I need. Use `q{0-9a-zA-Z"}` to record key strokes into a buffer. Position the cursor at the begging of the variable name, then `cw` and type `env['']`. Next move the cursor back one space to the last quote and paste the buffer filled from the `cw` command with `P`. Finally, reuse the recording with `@{0-9a-z".=*}` for each variable.

Comment: Press @ twice to repeat last macro