# Need script/function/command to surround text with other text

Tags: vim

I'm new to scripting in Vim. I need to write a script that surrounds a piece of text with other text. For example:

```
\surroundingtext{surrounded text}
```

(yes it is for LaTeX). I want to either highlight "surrounded text" and issue the command, or have "surrounded text" the result of a regular expression command.

I guess the question is, how to put this in a function?

Thanks,
Jeremy

Comment: You might want to post this on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I do:

```
vnoremap <buffer> <leader>sur "zc\surroundingtext{<C-R>z}<Esc>
```

This creates a visual-mode mapping where you can characterwise-visual select (`v`) the text that you want to surround, type `\sur` (assuming a default `mapleader` of `\`) and the text will be surrounded by the text you specified.

- `"z` specifies register 'z'
- `c` tells vim to change the visually selected text, placing the original text in register 'z'
- `\surroundingtest` is the left-side
- `<C-R>z` tells Vim to paste register 'z'
- `}` is the right-side
- `<Esc>` puts you back in normal-mode

I also take it a step further and create normal-mode and insert-mode mappings as well:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <leader>sur i\surroundingtext{}<Esc>i
inoremap <buffer> <leader>sur \surroundingtext{}<Esc>i
```

You could place these mappings in your `~/.vimrc` file but they would be mapped for every `filetype`.

A better place for them would be your `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` file so they're only mapped when your `filetype` is `tex`.  Create the parent directories if they don't already exist.

This assumes that the filetype is correctly set to `tex` and you have filetype plugins enabled:

```
filetype plugin on
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the trick. Thanks! I almost never think about using maps. I should consider them more often.  I have put the map into a local plugin file so it won't affect all the files I open. The longer I use Vim, the more I realize how much there is to learn about it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I asked a very similar question a few weeks ago. [How to repeatedly add text on both sides of a word in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192800/how-to-repeatedly-add-text-on-both-sides-of-a-word-in-vim) There are good starting points in the answers.

I would recommend using visual selection since you need to surround arbitrary chunks of text instead of a single word. Enter visual selection mode by pressing `v`, then select the text you wish to surround. Next record a macro with the desired modification using the following key strokes:

```
qa        " record a macro in buffer a
x         " cut the selected text
i         " enter insert mode
prefix    " type the desired prefix
<esc>     " exit insert mode
p         " paste the cut text
a         " enter insert mode after the pasted text
postfix   " type the desired postfix
<esc>     " exit insert mode
q         " stop recording
```

To reuse the macro simply visually select the next block you would like to modify and press `@a`.

This may be too cumbersome if the surrounding text varies frequently, or if you want this to persist across editing sessions. In that case you would probably want to write a vim script function to handle it in a more robust way.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about macros. Your explanation is clear. However, I need this to be a function because I will be using it regularly across many Vim sessions. I'll take a look at your other question to see how it was finished.